# How to Exclude Formula Property in Loading Objects

Tags: nhibernate, properties, formula

Recently I had to use formula properties in my NHibernate mapping. My intention was to use the formula properties as query filters and they appear to be working fine in that regard.

However I did not realize the side effect of using formula properties. NHibernate also tries to populate the property using the defined formula when loading objects.

My question is, is it possible to prevent NHibernate from populating formula property when loading objects?

To be more specific, the problem I am having is that NHibernate tries to use what I have in the formula in the SQL select statement, which I do not want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your property mapping you can specify `access="noop"`. This won't populate any fields/properties.

You can then implement a [custom loader](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-load). To exclude your noop properties from being loaded when calling `Session.Load` or `Session.Get`

Comment: I am using NHiberate 2.2. Is `noop` is valid value for the access attribute? I got a compile error on this.

Comment: @John, it should be, see this post http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/10/nhibernate-ndash-query-only-properties.aspx

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the website which talks about a very interesting feature of NHibernate. But it does not seem to relate to my question. Maybe I have not made myself clear. I have edited my original post. But here it is again. Basically what I want is that whatever the formula is, it can not appear in the SQL select statement. For example, my formula is defined as `formula=" OrderPrice < 10"`. It is meant to be used as a filter in the WHERE clause, not as one of the SELECT items. Hopefully I made myself clearer now. Thanks again.

Comment: @Joh, perhaps you can post your mapping as I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @oh, 
Here is my mapping: `<property name="IsCallHour" type="integer" formula="(dbo.fn_IsCallTime(default))"/>`. It is purely for used as filter in the SQL query. I do not want `(dbo.fn_IsCallTime(default))` to appear in SQL 'SELECT' statement when NHibernate loads the object that has this property.